# Java: Overhead in executing StringBuilder.indexOf() that concatenates a variable and literal

Tags: java, string, performance, indexof

Is there a performance overhead in executing `sb.indexOf(c + "")` 
where `c` is of type `Character` or `char` and `sb` is `StringBuilder` object?

Comment: `c` is really a `Character`, not a `char`? Why?

Comment: Can live with a `char`. Updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `String.valueOf`

```
builder.indexOf(String.valueOf(c));
```

There are good things about this approch.

1. Clean code
2. String.valueOf creates String object using char[] from passed char like`char data[] = {c};` so no additional operation is required.

`2` is really a micro optimization and I would always go for option `1` i.e. "clean code".

For what it's worth, here's the bytecode generated by the concatenation version:

```
new #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
invokespecial #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
aload_1
invokevirtual #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc #8; //String 
invokevirtual #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual #10; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual #11; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.indexOf:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

As you can see, it creates a second `StringBuilder`, does two `append` calls, and then a `toString`. In contrast, here's the `String.valueOf` version:

```
aload_0
aload_1
invokestatic #12; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual #11; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.indexOf:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

That just hands the `Character` (which has already been automatically unboxed into a `char`) off to `String.valueOf`. So what does that do? Let's look at the JDK source code:

```
public static String valueOf(char c) {
    char data[] = {c};
    return new String(0, 1, data);
}
```

So it creates a new one-character array and hands off directly to the `String` constructor. Very likely to be more efficient.

But again, it's probably a micro-optimization. The `String.valueOf` call makes the code clearer, which is the main thing.

Comment: What makes you think that's better?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  It creates string from char[] which is only character. So it is faster than creating string from char using concatenation.

Comment: @AmitD - have you looked at the bytecodes generated for `ch + ""`?

Comment: @ Amit: Looking at the generated bytecode, I'd have to agree. The concatenation version creates a second `StringBuilder` and does two `append` calls and then a `toString`. The `String.valueOf` version just calls `String.valueOf`, which (looking at the source) creates the one-character array you mentioned and calls the `String` constructor. That just feels more efficient. Not that it's likely to matter, but still.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the analysis and confirmation :).

Comment: Amit, TJ: Thanks for the quick response and thorough analysis.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: Would the concatenation or String.valueOf result in a literal on the Heap?

Comment: @MintUser: I'm not entirely sure I follow you. The concatenation version would certainly involve a literal (`""`), but it will be interned and the odds are pretty high you already have that literal in the intern pool, so it's a net-zero thing in that using the literal in this case probably doesn't add to the pool. But both approaches create temporary objects that will be allocated and then (at some point) released. Again, though, unless this is a mega-tight loop, it just doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The `String` and `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` classes in Java uses brute force method of pattern first exact string matching algorithm. This algorithm involves checking for an occurrence of the pattern at all positions of the text starting at some position and moving by one position, so I feel `String.indexOf` and `StringBuilder.indexOf` will be identical in terms of performance.

However, the `String` class has a `indexOf(char c)` method while `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` have `indexOf(String s)` methods, so if you searching for a character in `StringBuilder` you will have to first cast the char to String. In your example, that would probably be the only overhead.

Note: The brute force algorithm employed by String and StringBuilder classes are enough when you are dealing with small or medium sized texts but when dealing with large documents, it is preferable to use more sophisticated search string search algorithms.